# How to dynamically focus on first input element in a form with select2 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a lot of forms. I don't want to manually add id on each first input element on my forms. Some of my forms starts with a select2 element. How can I dynamically focus the first input element or the first select2.

```
$('form:first *:input[type!=hidden]:first').focus();
```

I used the code above but it does not work on forms starting with a select2.

Comment: If you execute that line of code after instantiating the Select2 plugin it should work.